# How to compress a CSS selector string, using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Maybe there's a library that does this already? All I could find is online tools. The reason I want to do this in javascript is because I want to know that the string `a > b, a` is the same as `a> b,a`. If I can compress it as CSS, all versions will end up as the same string.

A better explanation of why I'm trying to do this: I wrote a jQuery plugin for myself to cache  jQuery selectors (this stuff`$('div')`). It works by storing a key value pair, where the key is my selector string, and the value is the DOM elements found. This is why I'd like to compare CSS selector strings, otherwise I'd be storing different keys that are essentially the same selector.

Comment: What do you mean by compress? Why do you want to compress selectors anyway?

Comment: Why do you need to do that in runtime?

Comment: It sounds like you're actually asking if there's a way to *normalize* the selectors *(or at least the whitespace)* for the purpose of comparison. Is that right?

Comment: @user1689607 exactly. And why I'm wanting to do this has to do with caching jQuery selectors.

Comment: so you want to parse a CSS document and normalize these selectors?  Or are you parsing a jQuery script to normalize any existing selector strings?

Comment: Also, jQuery selectors are not CSS selectors. I'm not even sure they follow the same grammar, even if they look alike.

Comment: I just want to parse a single string at a time in javascript.

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar: Why do you want to cache selector strings? I don't understand what benefit there would be, unless you're doing it on the server-side to reduce the download.

Comment: So you need a function `normalizeJQuerySelector()` that takes a single string input, treats it as a jQuery selector, normalizes the whitespace, and returns the result.  Is that right?

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar can you look at my answer and see if that works for you... to normalize basically to normalize you'd minify then split a string and sort it.

Answer (score -1):

Uglify.js (https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) can let you automate compression of CSS. It will strip out all unnecessary white spaces and comments. This should allow you to normalize whatever you want. You will need to look at Uglify source and attempt to extract just the needed components.

When I experimented on: http://refresh-sf.com/yui/ it seems the selector was always minified appropriately (although that was using YUI not uglifyjs). The only remaining issue is the difference between a>b,b and b,a>b. For that I would recommend first minifying then splitting by ','; then sorting the array alphabetically; and finally rejoining the split array. Once done you can use that value as the hash.

Comment: Because what is required is not minification or compression of CSS files, but rather normalising CSS selectors embedded in JS code so that two selector strings that differ only in, for example, whitespace used, are considered the same.

Comment: @GregL If you minify a valid piece of CSS won't it also normalize? If you have extra spaces it should remove them all. Compression is normalization in this case. Try a > b, a { background:#000; } vs a>b,a vs a >   b,a {} on http://refresh-sf.com/yui/ . All variations should result in the same thing.

Comment: True, it's probably better than just removing whitespace, as I presume there are more intricacies to minification than just removing whitespace. Can you programmatically call Uglify.js on small strings like that? FYI, I wasn't the downvoter. I was just explaining why I thought you might have been downvoted.

Comment: @GregL thanks! I added more details to the proposed solution. UglifyJS is just javascript. It will need some modification for sure, but I think forking uglify is the best option here since its already in JS and could probably be ported. If the final solution is small enough I'd love to see a pull request into jquery. I wonder what sort of cases we aren't thinking about.